# issue in AjaxControlToolKit 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i installed `AjaxControlToolKit 15.1` to use it with my asp.net website
i include it in the `web.config` as assembly

```
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
```

i define it as a `control` with tagname

```
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="cc1" />
```

this is the piece of code in my aspx page where i use elemnts of the toolkit

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1"
TabStripPlacement="TopRight" Width="23%" Font-Size="Large">
    <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="menu" >
    </cc1:TabPanel></cc1:TabContainer>
```

my website works properly, but when i navigate out of the page with ajax control it gives me this error

> Unhandled exception at line 1, column 56851 in
>   http://localhost:6159/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length'
>   of undefined or null reference

and this error occurs exactly here

> $removeHandler(element, name, events[name]);

here is the code

```
   removeHandlers: function(element, events) {
    // Removes a set of event handlers from an element
    // This is NOT the same as $clearHandlers which removes all delegates
    // from a DomElement. This rather removes select delegates 
    // from a specified element and has a matching signature as $addHandlers
    // "element" - the element to modify
    // "events" - the template object that contains event names and delegates

    for (var name in events) {
        $removeHandler(element, name, events[name]);
    }
},
```

what to do please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and error message in a WebForms ASP.NET 4.5.2 app.

I commented out an included script: ""

and the problem went away. Not sure why but I hope it helps.

UPDATE Actually I had downloaded the latest AjaxControlToolkit code at https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest and rebuilt with my project and that is was really fixed my particular problem.

(sorry I had pasted the unquoted script code in the original post and it did not show up in the answer.)

Comment: what do you mean with rebuilt it with your project?